# Using LetsEncrypt and Google webmaster tools with gitlab ce

Tags: ssl, gitlab, google-search-console, lets-encrypt

I have used `certbot` to obtain SSL certificates. At that time ubuntu's default apache server was listening on port 80. Assume my server is accessible via `example.com`.

Now, I am running a GitLab CE  9.4.4 server using the SSL certificate I have obtained earlier with letsencrypt. In `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` I same something like this

```
nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
```

(and similar lines with `registry_nginx` for the docker registry.)

However, `certbot renew` fails, when it tries to renew my certificates, since `/var/www/.well-known` is not accessible via `http://example.com/.well-known`.

A similar problem arises, when one tries to use Google webmaster tools. The default verification process requires you to upload a file named `googleXXXXXXX.html` into the server's root directory.

How can GitLab be configures to server static files in `.well-known` and files starting with `google`?

(Unfortunately, a Google search containing *gitlab* and *static files*, produces results about GitLab pages.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Via GitLab Webroot

The webroot of GitLab CE on Ubuntu is `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public` by default. You can copy the `googleXXXX.html` into this directory and point LetsEncrypt's webroot to this directory:

```
...
[renewalparams]
authenticator = webroot
installer = None
account = SOMEHASH
[[webroot_map]]
example.com = /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public
```

### Via GitLab Config

**Configure LetsEncrypt**

Open the letencrupt renewal configuration, e.g. `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf`, and adjust the options, such that the web root points to `/var/www/letsencrypt`:

```
...
[renewalparams]
authenticator = webroot
installer = None
account = SOMEHASH
[[webroot_map]]
example.com = /var/www/letsencrypt
```

Create the directories `/var/www/letsencrypt` and `/var/www/letsencrypt/.well-known`. The latter directory will host the verification challenge files.

**Configure Webmaster tools**

Create the directory `/var/www/google` and download the `googleXXXX.html` it into the newly created directory.

**Configure GitLab** (for LetsEncrypt and Webmaster tools)

Open `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and add the following two lines.

```
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "location ^~ /.well-known { root /var/www/letsencrypt; }\n"
nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] << "location ^~ /google { root /var/www/google; }\n"
```

Reconfigure your gitlab server by running

```
gitlab-ctl reconfigure
```

All requests, which start with `/.will-known` will now be forwarded to the `/var/www/letsencrypt` directory. Similarly, all requests starting with `/google` are forwarded to the directory `/var/www/google`. (Please note, that this approach makes users or group starting with *google* inaccessible. In this case you can change the gitlab config to include the full name of your `googleXXXX.html`)